# iOS app Crash due to "Could not load NIB in bundle"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

when i run the simulator there is a crash and i don't know why it give me this 
"
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController_iPhone''" 
 could anyone help me ?

Comment: The error message states what is wrong `Could not load NIB in bundle`. Make sure that the nib file exists and is added to the target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that a "ViewController_iPhone.xib" file has been added to your project?

Either add it to your project/target, or (if it already there) check the nib name you are using on the statement that is causing the crash, or check your info.plist file if the crash happens at startup.

If everything is correct, clean your project and build again.

Comment: i don't have ViewController_iPhone.xib" file i have one and it's name ViewController.xib where i shall check this crash

Comment: how do you instantiate the controller? is the main controller of your app? please, check my edit for more hints...

Comment: yes it is the main one which it appear when i create the project

Comment: check your info.plist file, you should find the xib mentioned there... or simply rename the existing ViewController.xib to ViewController_iPhone.xib

Comment: thanks it work now but still make a crash for other reason i'm trying to find out what is that reason

Comment: reason: '[<ViewController 0x6c14970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pickerPressed.'

Comment: ok, so now your nib file is loaded. this fixes your original problem. only, your nib and controller are inconsistent: it seems that you defined a `pickerPressed` in your nib, but your controller has no such property. Check you nib for all of its connections to look for "dangling" connections and fix that.

Comment: the problem was i rewrite the name of the buttons and i didn't update the connection , thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got the same, when working on iOS7 and get the crash when running on iOS6

To solve it:

If you are using xCode5 you should go to your Xib file and change the "Interface Builder Document" to view as iOS6.1 or earlier or change the "opens in" xcode version to 4.6 instead of 5.0

It solved  the issue for me